# Highlight and sorting issue when populating table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make my table have a checkbox column for each row, and also the rows to highlight on hover. It works properly when the data is static declared on html files, however when retrieving the data from server (I'm using $.getJSON) the sorting becomes a mess and the highlight stops working.

Also it shows this message for each row in the table.

> DataTables warning: Requested unknown parametr '5' from the data
>   source for row 0

Here is my code:

```
$(function () 
{
    var oTable;
    var tRow; 

    var checkboxIdsArray = new Array();
    var allChecked = false;

        // To generate the checkbox for each row
        var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
    var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
    nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox" />';
        nCloneTd.className = "center";

    // Deal with the checbox selection  
    $('#op_checkbox').live('click', function()
    {
        var operatorId = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    });

    $('#example thead tr').each(function () 
    {
        this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]); // Add the header before the first header
        });

    // Instantiate the DataTable
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({"aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]});

    $.getJSON('../../controller/UserController.php/getUsers',
    function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, item)
        {
            oTable.fnAddData(
                [
                    item.idUser,
                    item.nameUser,
                    item.telephoneUser,
                    item.cnpjUser,
                    item.inscEstUser
                ]
            );
        });

        $('#example tbody tr').each(function () 
            {
                this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]); // Add the checkbox to the td's
            });
    });

    // Deals with the highlight of the rows 
    $('#example tbody tr').hover(function() 
        {
            tRow = this; 
            $(this).children().addClass('highlighted');
        }, 
        function() 
        {
            var nTrs = oTable.fnGetNodes();
            $(tRow).children().removeClass('highlighted');
        } 
    );

    // Deals with the export options
    var oTableTools = new TableTools( oTable, 
    {
            "aButtons": 
            [
                {
                    "sExtends":    "div",
                    "sButtonText": "Hello world"
                }
            ]
    });

    $('#demo').before( oTableTools.dom.container );

        // Deals with the check all button click
    $('#checkall_link').live('click', function()
    {
        var i = 0; 
        if(!allChecked)
        {
            $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function()
            {
                allChecked = true;
                $('#checkall_link').text('Uncheck all');
                this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked = true; // Set all checkbox to checked
                checkboxIdsArray[i] = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id; // Store the current checkbox id the checkboxIds array
                i++; 
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function()
            {
                allChecked = false;
                $('#checkall_link').text('Check all');
                this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked = false; // Set all checkbox to checked
                checkboxIdsArray = [];
                console.log(checkboxIdsArray);
            });
        }
    });

    $('#manage_del').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'disabled')
        {
            alert("disabled");          
        }
        else
        {
            alert("enabled");
        }
    });

    $('#manage_new').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'disabled')
        {
            alert("disabled");          
        }
        else
        {
            alert("enabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is how my table looks like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGm0F.jpg

As you can see in the arrow in the right side, it creates another column (maybe because the checkbox is being added), also the left arrows you can see that the 2nd column is highlighted, but the checked header is the 1st (with checkboxes). And when I hover the rows, it doesn't get highlighted.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Now using delegate(), but it doesn't work yet.

```
// Deals with the highlight of the rows 
$('#example tbody').delegate('tr', 'hover', function() 
{
    tRow = this; 
    $(this).children().addClass('highlighted');
}, 
function() 
{
    var nTrs = oTable.fnGetNodes();
    $(tRow).children().removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Comment: I imagine that every time your table changes you need to re-run the code that assigns the hover functions, because they (the `tr` elements) are being destroyed and recreated when the data changes, and thus your hover functions go away with them.

Comment: @Cory sorry but how would I do that?

Comment: Check out Code Addict's answer. He's on the right track. Using `delegate()` or `on()` will attach your hover events to all matching elements *now* or *in the future*, so you don't have to worry about when your elements are created or destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use delegate personally (mostly because I never did get my hover example working for you with dynamic content)

Here is some example code to show you how to use delegate:

Sample setup for a thumbnail list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" />
        <p>some title text</p>            
    </li>
</ul>​


// attach the handler via delegate()
$(document).delegate("li", "hover", function() { // this works because the delegate function looks for all li's that are children to the document.
    $(this).children('p').fadeToggle("fast");
});

// after you've attached the handler create some elements.
setTimeout(function() {
    var list = $('ul'),
        node = list.children('li'),
        i = 25;
    while (i) {
        list.append(node.clone());
        i--;
    }
}, 1000);​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/58UvN/3/)